# Prevent duplicate row insertion php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert multiple records from a text box into a mysql table.
If I enter more than 2 records, it's inserting duplicates.
Here's the code.
What am I doing wrong?

Some more info

Table info

```
id (int) primary auto_increment
email (varchar)
imei (varchar)
date_ordered (datetime)
status(varchar)
```

Since it's only the beginning, I have no problems with changing the table structure.

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$now = time():
$status = "1";

$imeis = $_POST['imeis'];
$row = explode("\n", $imeis);

foreach ($row as $key => $imei)
{
    $imei = mysql_real_escape_string($imei);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE imei = '$imei'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        $query1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO orders (email, imei, date_ordered, status) VALUES ('$email', '$imei', '$now', '$status')";
        $result1  = mysqli_query($link, $query1) OR die("fml");

        if ($result1)
        {   
            echo "Added $imei<br>";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        echo "<B>$imei</B> already there<br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: this part maybe tricky `OR die("fml")`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan That's not really helping. @OP The first problem might be `INSERT IGNORE`. That's like saying: I don't care if there's a duplicate, just ignore it and continue. Secondly, `OR die("fml")` isn't helping you at all. It would tell you there was a problem but not what the problem is. Untill production, you should use `OR die("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link))` so you actually get some usefull information out of it.

Comment: @icecub thanks, useful for me.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Not sure how it's usefull to you, but you're welcome. Seems like OP has been busy trying to surpress any errors instead of actually solving them. That probably got him into this mess

Comment: @icecub if someday i start for mysql(as an oracle man), i think will be a good info for me, thanks.

Comment: Please include a description of your table. If you happen to have a primary key, say 'email', then every line of 'imeis' will be replaced, so you will end up with only the last line. If this is the case, you need to rewrite your table, and have a unique primary id.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want each value of `imei` to be unique in your table. It;s a guess, but it looks like what you're doing.

You do that in SQL by defining the `imei` column to be unique: that is, by creating a unique index on it.  Your present table has an `id` as a unique (primary) key. You can easily create another one.